# Webpack aliases do not work

Tags: javascript, webpack

I set `resolve.alias` in `webpack.config.js`

`alias: {
  '$': 'jquery',
  '_': 'underscore'
}`

and require modules in my javascript file like this.

`var $ = require('$');
var _ = require('_');`

then there comes an error

`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module '$'`

I try to display error details and I find out that it still try to looking for  modules named `$` or `_`, not `jquery` or `underscore`.

So why doesn't the `alias` config work? Do I set a wrong config?

`webpack.config.js`

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var config = require('../config');

var projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');
var buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'demo');

module.exports = {
// eval-source-map is faster for development
devtool: '#eval-source-map',
entry: {
    miceui: ['webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        path.resolve(projectRoot, 'index')]
},
output: {
    path: buildPath,
    filename: '[name].js'
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': config.dev.env
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'index.html',
        inject: true
    })
],


module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.htm(l?)$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader') },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
        { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' }
    ]
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.coffee', '.html', '.css', '.scss'],
    alias: {
        '$': 'jquery',
        '_': 'underscore'
    }
}
```

};

Comment: Would `var $ = require('jquery');` work for you?

Comment: I use webpack to package a small library, it depends on `jquery` or `zepto`. i want make it more flexible

Comment: Okay. Any chance you answer my question though? Not to say it's not immediately obvious how aliasing something makes it "flexible".

Comment: Yes, iit is OK with `var $ = require('jquery')`. But it is not what i want

Comment: If `require('jquery')` then alias would also work for sure. Show the complete config.

Comment: i have posted complete config

Comment: Try `alias: {   '$$': 'jquery' ...`

Comment: Yes !  '$$' is ok. That's really wired. Maybe it's resolved as regular expression